# Item won't add to cart in woocommerce after a popup is triggered

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

So I need to add a simple popup notice in woocommerce for all products from 2 different product categories.

The popup is triggered by clicking on the add to cart button and it will show a simple message with a button to confirm that the customer understands certain conditions of sale. Once they click confirm, I want the item (and quantity) to be added to the cart.

I currently have the bare bones of what I want but it is only half working. The popup displays when add to cart is clicked on any item within my 2 selected product categories.

However, when you click "confirm" the popup disappears and the page refreshes but no items are added to the cart.

Below is a sample of my php code from my functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_custom_popup' );

function my_custom_popup() {
  global $post;
  $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
  $display_popup = false;
  foreach ( $product_cats as $product_cat ) {
    if ( in_array( $product_cat->slug, array( 'hoodies', 'music' ) ) ) {
      $display_popup = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if ( $display_popup ) {
    ?>
    <div class="product_cat_popup" style="display: none;">
        <h1>Store Notice</h1>
        <p>Description</p>
        <button class="confirm_button">Confirm</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.product_cat_popup').show();
        
        $('.confirm_button').click(function() {
          $('.product_cat_popup').hide();
          $('form.cart').submit();
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
  }
}
```

and my css is as below (although, I doubt there is much importance to it);

```
.product_cat_popup {
    width: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  
  .product_cat_popup p {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .product_cat_popup button {
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you are using the click event you are stopping the Add to Cart button from executing the original function it was using to add that product to the cart by using 'e.preventDefault()'. See below

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

After the popup is closed, you will likely need the Add To Cart button to execute what is required of it to add that product to the cart.

Edit: Have you also confirmed that the hidden fields' values for the Add To Cart form are correct? These are the hidden fields usually found below the 'Add to Cart' button in the source code.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for taking your time to respond. I should have also pointed out that I am pretty much useless with JS therefore I am not sure what you mean. Should I not use the click event on the add to cart button to trigger the popup or is there an alternative way to use the click event but not stop the original function?

Comment: No I think the way you are doing it is correct. Your code looks like it should be doing just that by including `$('form.cart').submit();` I've just attempted doing something like this on a WooCommerce site I manage and it works by adding the product to the cart. Are you getting any errors server-side or in the dev tools console?

Comment: No there is no errors in dev tools, except for 1 relating to "browser sync client" which is a part of the local wordpress app. I thought this might be conflicting so I tried on a demo server but the popup isn't even displaying at all on there. Perhaps its easier to buy a plugin lol